# nested if statement: expected declaration or statement at end of input

Tags: c, if-statement

The assignment given by our teacher was to create a program that asked for asked for two integers `x` and `y` and one character `z`. The letter entered for `z` could be `a` and it would add the two integers, `s` would subtract them, `m` multiply and `d` divide.

The teacher tried to explain multiple 'if' 'else' statements in class; however, I'm afraid I cannot make heads or tails of where the missing '{' is. If someone who better understands this could explain why and where the missing '{' is that would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char let;
int x;
int y;
int a;
int s;
int m;
int d;

printf("Enter command letter \n");
scanf("%c", &let);

printf("Enter both integers \n");
scanf("%d%d%c", &x, &y);

if (let==a)
{
    a=x+y;
    printf("x+y is %d \n", a);
}

else
{
    if (let==s)
    {
            s=x-y;
            printf("x-y is %d \n", s);
    }

    else
    {
             if (let==m)
            {
                    m=x*y;
                    printf("x*y is %d \n", m);
            }

    else
    {
                    d=x/y;
                    printf("x/y is %d \n", d);
    }
}

return(0);

}
```

Comment: Added the corrected version for you, it's really simple as you'll find

Comment: Which system are you using?  Doesn't your editor provide you with a way to find the matching `}` for an `{`?  Doesn't it provide automatic indentation?

Comment: Unrelated problem: You compare `if (let==a)` (and similar for s,m,d), that means you compare the scanned letter to the uninitialised variable `int a;`. You should compare `if (let == 'a')` to the character constant `'a'` (etc.).

Answer (score 4):

It's the typical indent problem.

One thing you know for sure is that you can't have two 'else's for the same IF. If you follow your code you'll see:

```
    if (let==s)
    {
            s=x-y;
            printf("x-y is %d \n", s);
    }

    else
    {
             if (let==m)
            {
                    m=x*y;
                    printf("x*y is %d \n", m);
            }

    else
    {
                    d=x/y;
                    printf("x/y is %d \n", d);
    }
```

This is wrong.

Now the corrected version

```
    if (let==s)
    {
            s=x-y;
            printf("x-y is %d \n", s);
    }

    else
    {
             if (let==m)
            {
                    m=x*y;
                    printf("x*y is %d \n", m);
            }

            else //REINDENTED THIS ELSE, AND THE ERROR BECOMES VISIBLE
            {
                    d=x/y;
                    printf("x/y is %d \n", d);
            }

     }//THIS IS THE ONE MISSING
```

Comment: Okay, great thank you for the explanation! I understand what your pointing out. Idk why the rest of the script didn't show but, either way now I know what to look for! thanks again

Comment: I just wanted to make things simple for you, the rest of the code is okay :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two `} else {` blocks.

You need to have only *one* `} else {` block that is executed only if every `if (...) {` and `} else if (...) {`  isn't run.

For example:

```
int x = 4;

if (x == 1) {
  // Do stuff
} else if (x == 2) {
  // Do stuff because x isn't 1
} else if (x == 3) {
  // Do stuff because x isn't 1 or 2
} else {
  // Do stuff because x isn't 1, 2 or 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The last `else` belongs to

```
if (let==m)
```

so the next `}` closes the previous else, and the `main()` is missing its closing `}`

It is generally best to keep the `if`/`else` pairs indented to the same level to avoid these mistakes